# Latest texlive 2019 update broke files with novel class

Tags: errors, luatex, texlive-2019

The example files supplied with the novel class package and my own files using this package no longer compile (lualatex) after the latest update. There are everything ok with Texlive 2018 and before the update with 2019. But I don't know exactly what package at what time broke the compilation process.

Edited:
Here is the complete compilation log (hitting enter once):

```
    This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./TSWLatexianTemp_000049.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.171 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel.cls
Document Class: novel 2018/04/26 v1.52 LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty `Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/silence/silence.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textpos/textpos.sty
Package: textpos 2019/04/15 1.9.1, absolute positioning of text on the page
Grid set 16 x 16 = 0.0pt x 0.0pt
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/noindentafter/noindentafter.sty

Package noindentafter Warning: Patching `\end' failed!
(noindentafter)                `\NoIndentAfter...' commands won't work.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/magaz/magaz.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pgf.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-FileData.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-CGATSTR001.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-LayoutSettings.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-Fonts.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-DropCap.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-TextMacros.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-HeadFootStyles.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-ChapterScene.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-Images.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-Footnotes.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-Obsolete.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-CGATSTR001.clo)
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font libertinusserif-semibold.otf not found.". (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-microtype.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-CalculateLayout.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-PostLayout.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-pdfx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/xcolor-patch.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hopatch.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/psdextra.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/novel/novel-xmppacket.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/se-pdfdoc.def))
No file TSWLatexianTemp_000049.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty))...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-features.lua:252: bad argument #1 to 'stringgsub' (string expected, got boolean).
<to be read again> 
\scan_stop: 
￼l.19 \begin{document}

? 

! Package fontspec Error: The font "LibertinusSerif" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

￼l.19 \begin{document}

?
```

Comment: The last lines of the log are often not so useful, as many errors after the first are spurious, is that the first error, or did you get other errors before the luaotfload one?

Comment: I replaced the partly log through the complete log.

Comment: The `{}` button in the editor would make it readable, I'll do it this time

Comment: Sorry and thank you

Comment: so your first error is that the noindentafter package needs an update, the luaotfload problem might be a fontspec issue, I'll look...

Comment: Ulrike hinted it may be due to this https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/403

Comment: Ok. Hopefully the issue will be addressed soon.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the interaction between newest fontspec, luaotfload and polyglossia. It didn't compile and returned several errors of fonts not found. Restoring previous versions of those packages solved it. As David has pointed the bug is already being discussed in https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/403

Comment: @fdiog Which versions of the three packages you reinstall? I tried only luaotfload version 3.1 with no success. I put the tld package in the directory which I get  from "kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME". Afterwards I run "sudo mktexlsr". But from the log for me it is not clear if the replaced luaotfload was used.

Comment: @Nik I think the problem lies mostly on fontspec. I restored to fontspec 2.7d, polyglossia 1.45 and luaotfload 3.1 (Current and problematic versions on TeX Live updates are  2.7e, 1.46 and 3.11 respectively). I can't help you with the process since I did it all with the TeX Live Utility.

Comment: @fdiog May I ask you how have you done it? The packages in the TeX Live Utility deleted? And then? Is there an option to choose from different versions for the update/reinstall process?

Comment: @Nik In TLU there is an option for configuring backups. I just selected the problematic packages, deleted them and restore previous versions from the backups tab. I think one must have automatic backups turned on for that to work.

Comment: @fdiog Thanks. TeX Live Utility: Preferences: Remove packages to match the server when updating. Configure: Configure Automatic Backups Not sure what to use. I've downloaded luaotfload.tds.zip 3.1There are no tds packages for the other two. Then polyglossia 1.45. I've got the tds structure from polyglossia.tds.zip 1.46. Then fontspec 2.7d. This package comes without sty files. I followed the readme: texlua build.lua install. But this didn't work. What worked was: luatex fontspec.ins. I took the tds structure from fontspec.tds.zip 2.7g. Put everything under ~/Library/texmf (mac os x). Success.

Comment: With the newest updates of the above mentioned packages novel.sty is working again.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the `novel` document class, returned after a hiatus, with a different username here.

Awhile back, I was informed that there were issues regarding `novel` and recent TeXlive. Although it still works for me (TeXlive 2022 on Linux), I was not sure if others would have a problem. So I requested CTAN to retire the document class.

My point: If `novel` continues to work, use it. EDIT: Thanks for the comment, @Nik. Contrary to what I wrote earlier, I expect that I will upload a minor update to `novel'. Maybe a month from now. It will not affect existing documents, but may make some new documents compile faster. And, I will let CTAN know that all is OK.

Comment: For me it works too. And I'm using it. I published a small book with it for my family last Christmas. Thank you for the package. I would plead for keeping it on CTAN. But of course I don't know if special measures were taken by other developers to keep the package running. But as I said, I personally would be happy if it stays.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm getting an error concerning FloatImage. The first image is read in with InlineImage just fine as before. 
And the line with FloatImage worked before as well. But may be something went wrong with my latex update.  

`[6] (./luise.tex [1<./Frei-1.jpeg>]
./luise.tex:47: Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@scalex ->\@TMratio 
                        
l.47 \FloatImage[ht, 0, -5\nbs]{Frei-2s.png}
                                          
./luise.tex:47: Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@scalex ->\@TMratio `

Comment: @Nik Bug confirmed. Will fix, but not today. Self-help: In file `novel-Images.sty`, look for the optional argument `[Scale=\@TMratio]` and delete it. Previously, `novel` had a feature that allowed you to do things that many print services disapprove. It was not necessary, so I removed it in the update. But that piece of code was left behind.

Comment: It works again. Thank you!

Comment: @Nik Would you post your comment as a question, so that I can answer it? Not that I need the rep, but there may be others with that problem, and having a question will help them. Unfortunately, the bug is baked into TeXlive 2022, and the fix (already uploaded to CTAN) will not be installable until TeXlive 2023.