# Latest version of the novel class doesn't work with TexLive 2022

Tags: novel

I'm getting an error concerning `FloatImage` from `novel.cls`. The first image is read in with `InlineImage` just fine as before. And the line with `FloatImage` worked before as well.

```
[6] (./luise.tex [1<./Frei-1.jpeg>] ./luise.tex:47: Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@scalex ->\@TMratio                           
l.47 \FloatImage[ht, 0, -5\nbs]{Frei-2s.png}
`./luise.tex:47: Undefined control sequence. \Gin@scalex ->\@TMratio
```

A working fix is here in the comments further down.

[Latest texlive 2019 update broke files with novel class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524847/latest-texlive-2019-update-broke-files-with-novel-class/674138?noredirect=1#comment1687508_674138)

Answer (score 4):

Authoritative answer (I wrote the `novel` package).

Novel version 1.80 (released February 2022) has a bug. It is fixed in version 1.81 (March 2022). Unfortunately, version 1.81 did not make it to CTAN in time for the 2022 freeze. So if you use TeXlive 2022 (and only 2022), you will hit the bug with float images.

The fix to version 1.80 is very easy.

Method 1. Permanent fix. For this you must edit file `novel-Images.sty`.
Find this code `[\@TMratio]` and delete it.

Method 2. Per-document fix. Does not require access to `novel` code.
In your *tex document Preamble, add this line:

```
\makeatletter\def\@TMratio{1}\makeatother
```

The two methods are independent. It does not hurt, if you use both. And, the per-document fix will not hurt with any `novel` version.

Thanks for asking, @Nik.

EDIT: As is noted in comments, the initial distro of 2023 does not have version 1.81. Be patient, update.

EDIT2: How this happened: In version 1.80, I removed a lot of junk code that did nothing (experiments that never happened). But I left behind a variable that was initialized in the junk code. Shame on me. I should have known better, and initialized all variables in the top-level class file.

Comment: I've just installed TexLive 2023. The version of `novel.cls` which comes with this installation is still 1.80. So at the moment one or both of the two methods above should still be used also for 2023. Or one installs `novel.cls` from ctan manually.

Comment: @Nik Thanks for that note. Version 1.81 is at CTAN, so it is a matter of time delay. Besides, it will not affect anyone who does not float an image.